# how to display securimage error on same page

Tags: php, jquery, validation, spam-prevention

i do not find nor on [securimage website](http://www.phpcaptcha.org/), neighter on the forums how to display securimage error message on the same page where the contact form (with the anti-spam code) is found.

I have my contact form :

```
<form id="contactform" action="processform.php" method="post">           
    <div class="form-label">Nom</div>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    <div class="form-label">E-mail</div>
    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" />
    <div class="form-label">Sujet</div>
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" />                                   
    <div class="form-label">Message</div>
    <textarea class="span6" rows="4" name="message" id="message"></textarea>
    <div class="form-label-antispam">Anti-Spam Code</div>
    <input type="text" name="verif" id="verif" size="10" maxlength="6" />
    <div id="verif-box">
        <img id="captcha" src="/securimage/securimage_show.php" alt="Security Code" />
        <a class="veriflink" href="#" onClick="document.getElementById('captcha').src = '/securimage/securimage_show.php?' + Math.random(); return false">[Changer-Image]</a>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" id="send" name="button" value="Envoyer" />      
</form>
```

My processform.php starts as securimage requires and it gives an example but this example directs my error message to another page :

```
<?php

include_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/securimage/securimage.php';

$securimage = new Securimage();

if ($securimage->check($_POST['verif']) == false) {
  // the code was incorrect
  // you should handle the error so that the form processor doesn't continue

  // or you can use the following code if there is no validation or you do not know how
  echo "Le code de sécurité est incorrect.<br /><br />";
  echo "Retournez <a href='javascript:history.go(-1)'>à la page</a> et réessayez svp.";
  exit;
}
```

I have a contact.js file which put the other input error messages into a div on the same page of the contact form (together with a jquery.validate.min.js file) :

```
$(function() {
  // Validate the contact form
  $('#contactform').validate({
    // Specify what the errors should look like
    // when they are dynamically added to the form
    errorElement: "label",
    wrapper: "div",
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        error.insertBefore( element.parent().parent() );
        error.wrap("<div class='error-wrap'></div>");
    },

    // Add requirements to each of the fields
    rules: {
      name: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 3
      },
      email: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      message: {
        required: true,
        minlength: 20
      }
    },

    // Specify what error messages to display
    // when the user does something horrid
    messages: {
      name: {
        required: "Vous devez indiquer votre nom.",
        minlength: jQuery.format("Le nom doit contenir minimum {0} caracteres.")
      },
      email: {
        required: "Vous devez indiquer votre email.",
        email: "Vous devez indiquer un email valide."
      },
      message: {
        required: "Vous devez ecrire un message.",
        minlength: jQuery.format("Le message doit contenir minimum {0} caracteres.")
      }
    },

    // Use Ajax to send everything to processForm.php
    submitHandler: function(form) {
      $("#send").attr("value", "Envoyer...");
      $(form).ajaxSubmit({
        target: "#response",
        success: function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
          $(form).slideUp("slow");
          $("#response").html(responseText).hide().slideDown("slow");
        }
      });
      return false;
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: You can try putting everything inside the same page and use `action=""` instead of `action="processform.php"`

Comment: I do not have any idea how to put php codes (processform.php) into my html page which has the contactform... i do not think that is the solution... instead, i guess i should creat a validation.js for it (as the other input fields have) but i do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer...

I needed to install another jquery file additionally, called jquery.form.js which is full of codes what i do not understand... however if you have a problem to get the error message of securimage on the same page where your contact form is installed, let me know, i will send you the js file !